# MS-Access Cross-Form Support

Tags: ms-access, vba, global-variables

I'm a .NET / C# software engineer who's been recruited into a temporary job function I'm not thrilled with.

My company uses an MS-Access application for many of it's current functions.  The Visual Basic version in use for this is (v6.5).  The developer that assembled it (who's on vacation overseas at the moment) has a 'login' form that pops up before going to the 'switchboard' pages.  In order to maintain a 'global awareness' of logged in he leaves the form filled out and open -- hiding it from the user, then as he moves into other forms he reaches back into the hidden login form to determine login details.

While this is functional, it makes my OOP-orientated brain hurt a little bit.  Is this the right way to simulate a cache of global variables in this edition of MS-Access + VB, or merely one that our MS-Access developer settled for.  I found some online references to VBA source implementing global variables using the Global keyword but this doesn't seem to be supported in v6.5 (at least not in that fashion).

Does anyone have any clues on this or some outstanding MS-Access resources they can recommend so I can put this headache behind me?

Comment: Of course you have to ask yourself if this is something you really should 'fix'.  You did say this (flawed) approach is functional.

Comment: That's correct.  One of my responsibilities is upkeep on his  programming approaches (I didn't comment on other, still more disturbing things I've found digging through his 'solutions').

Comment: Thanks Ben, bugtussle... I'll review what you've both posted for us.

Comment: Is this a VB application, or an Access application? If the former, lose the VBA label. If the latter, lose the VB label. And the answer will depend on whether it's developed in Access (VBA) or has nothing at all to do with Access/Access-VBA at all (i.e., VB app using a Jet data store).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [bugtussle has said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3451989/ms-access-cross-form-support/3452035#3452035) you can use "global" variables inside modules.  Here's how:

Create a module called `LoginCredentials`.  Inside that module, you can declare variables as `public`, which in effect makes them global variables. For example:

```
public LoggedInUserId As Integer
public IsUserLoggedIn As Boolean
```

You can set and access those variables from other forms.  I prefer to always use the module name with the variable name in VBA so I know where the globals are declared, like so:

```
LoginCredentials.LoggedInUserId = 15

If LoginCredentials.IsUserLoggedIn Then
    'Do Something    '
End If
```

Granted, global variables only persist for the life of the application, so if it crashes or the user exists the application, you'll lose that data.  If you need the login credentials to "live" longer, consider storing the data in a database table.

As a side note, it's not at all uncommon for your OOP-oriented brain to hurt a little when working with VB6 /VBA. The language simply fails to fully implement OOP design features, but it's still possible to write better code when you know what you're doing.

Comment: As I said, global variables are reset if an unhandled error occurs, so they are chancy.

Comment: @Remou Did you miss the part of my answer, "so if it crashes or the user exists [sic] the application, you'll lose that data" and then suggest that he should consider storing data in a table?  You bring up a good point about unhandled errors, but he should be handling errors, or at least adding it as he goes.  I see Tony's point that if it's working, you may not need to fix it, but at the same time it's not a bad idea to look at other options.

Comment: They aren't reset if it's an Access MDE/ACCDE.

Comment: @Ben McCormick No I did not miss your point, my point is that this is a completed application that the OP has just been assigned to on a temporary basis and he or she may not have the time to check all the code to ensure that there are no unhandled errors, furthermore, the OP states that he or she is unfamiliar with VBA, so it may be a larger commitment of time than is acceptable.

Comment: @Remou That's a good point.  In general, I agree with the "if it ain't broke, don't fix it" model when you inherit legacy code, but God help you if you ever do have to fix it :-).

Comment: This did end up being our solution -- sorry for the delay... I got busy enough I had to put down Stack Overflow for a spell.

Answer (score 2):

This method is perfectly functional as global variables can be reset to null given code interruptions and such.  Especailly while you the developer are working in the code.

Also if it's working now why change it?

Answer (score 0):

He settled. The correct way to store global variables is to use a module.

http://www.blueclaw-db.com/access_database_global_variable.htm
http://forums.whirlpool.net.au/forum-replies-archive.cfm/528616.html
http://www.google.com/search?q=global+variables+in+vba+access

Comment: Global variables are reset if an unhandled error occurs, so they are chancy.

Comment: Global variables are a terrible way to handle something like this. Fake security is also not a good design (which is what it sounds like is being used).

Comment: @David What's the lesser of two evils?

Comment: I don't know which two evils you are asking about. The basic design outlined in the original question sounds bad both in WHAT is being implemented and in HOW it is implemented.

Comment: I think the two evils were 'global variables as described' and 'fake security', and he was right to say it.  I ended up tweaking the solution so it was both 'user safe' and 'IT saavy' even though I wasn't totally happy with how it all ended up.  The manager was content and ultimately that is generally the most important bar to overcome.